# Wanting to run a main program in a subdirectory of my hierarchy

Tags: python

I'm working on an open-source Python project with a moderately large (and steadily increasing) number of demo programs.

I moved the demo programs to a subdirectory named `demo/`, but then of course you cannot directly run them - if you do, Python takes the `demo/` subdirectory to be your root, and all your project imports fail.

My fix was to write a Demo.py program at the top level that lets you select which demo you want to run, but other developers and users of this project have (quite reasonably) complained about having to do this - they just want to run their demos directly.

I don't have a good solution for this.  The best idea I have is to put a code block like this at the top of each demo file:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  import sys
  from os.path import dirname
  sys.path.append(dirname(dirname(__file__)))
```

which does seem to work, though it's inelegant.

1. Is there a better solution?
2. If not, are there any obvious traps in this solution I should be aware of?

Comment: Why do you need to call dirname() twice?

Comment: `dirname(__file__)`, the directory containing the file you're executing, is always already in `sys.path`, so adding it would never be useful.  In the example described above, the Python script resides in a subdirectory of the main Python directory, so I need to add `dirname(dirname(__file__))`.  (Note that I did actually test my solution...)

Answer (score 0):

Tom, I will put this info here in case it's of any use to someone else: may lead you to something constructive but.. I find it impossible to generate documentation for the files in the demos directory. either

```
pydoc demos/Blur.py
```

or

```
python -m pydoc -w demos/Blur.py
```

just run the file. i.e. they do just what you're wanting. However I can't get any documentation. It works fine for all other directories!

Paddy